# Designing a mass attendance system with Excel and PowerQuery

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-2016

I am building an Excel spreadsheet for tracking a large number of personnel's daily attendance records. All data examples shown here are fictional, including the data structure. Only the gist of the data structure is shown, for illustrative purposes, as I am working on sensitive personal data on heavily locked down computers (i.e. no Internet, any form of scripting like VBA is banned, only Microsoft Office suite to manipulate data).

The main table for containing personnel records looks something like:

```
Master List

ID     Name     Home Address         Phone Number   Remarks
1      Alice    12 Somewhere Rd.     123456         remark 1 goes here
2      Bob      23 Someplace Dr.     234567         remark 2 goes here
3      Charlie  34 Somewhen Blvd.    345678         remark 3 goes here
```

As one can see, not all the information is required during attendance taking. As such, I perform a Power Query to slim it down to the essentials

```
Attendance

ID     Name      Remarks
1      Alice     remark 1 goes here
2      Bob       remark 2 goes here
3      Charlie   remark 3 goes here
```

After that, I appended the attendance entries to the right of the table.

```
Attendance

ID     Name      Remarks               2020/6/25   2020/6/26  ...............
1      Alice     remark 1 goes here    P           P          ...............
2      Bob       remark 2 goes here    P           VL         ...............
3      Charlie   remark 3 goes here    P           P          ...............
```

Finally, I [set up a self referencing table](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/) such that upon every refresh of the Attendance table, the attendance entries are preserved in their original rows, meaning that there would not be any problems if I insert a personnel somewhere in the middle.

However, I quickly ran into an issue when I realized I needed to tag every single special attendance entry (e.g. medical leave) with details regarding the leave itself. I initially tried adding comments onto the attendance cells directly, but realized that the comments does not follow the table generated by the Power Query (i.e. it stays in the original absolute cell location, meaning that an insertion of a new person will throw the bottom half of the table out of alignment by exactly one row).

I later attempted to use hyperlinks to link each attendance entry to a separate table which contained the remarks/details about the leave, but the link became unclickable after a query refresh.

How should I go about designing a remarks system for a per-day-per-person attendance system, and is my approach in the start where I query the master list, reduce the columns and then append more columns even the right approach to begin with?

Thank you!